# Making LoadControl XHR request in Mechanize

Tags: python, asp.net, mechanize

I have a Python script with Mechanize to navigate an external website. The website was apparently written in ASP.NET and is using dynamic controls. I'm trying to simulate an XHR to load a control (which is normally triggered by clicking on a `<button>`), but the ASP server returns a 500 error whenever I make the XHR. I matched the payload of the POST request of what is normally being sent.

Basically, I'm doing this:

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()

browser.open('https://external.site/page.html')
# Here would be code to parse the content and extract the
# parameters for the XHR.

# Now we're making the XHR to update the control:
body = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'request': {
                'control': 'Control_Name',
                'parameters': parameters,
            }
        })

request = mechanize.Request(
    url='https://external.site/server.asmx/LoadControl',
    data=body,
    method='POST',
)

response = browser.open(request)
```

When I do that, the browser raises an exception because it received a 500 from the server.

This may not be possible because of a CORS check or something similar, but I feel like I'm simply not making the request right. The URL and the data payload match what is normally being sent when I use the external website with a browser.

Is there a way to make LoadControl request via Mechanize?

For reference, the button on the website that I'm trying to navigate look like this:

```
<button type="button"
     data-focus="{&quot;LoadParams&quot;:{&quot;ControlName&quot;: [lots of key/value pairs here here]"}}"
     data-action="GB.LoadControl">Button</button>
```

When I click the button, the XHR contains this payload:

```
{
    "request": {
        [the data here matches data-focus from the button]
    }
}
```

And the request headers:

```
POST /MyService.asmx/LoadControl HTTP/1.1
Host: myservice.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 367
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.23.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.31 Safari/537.36 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 
Origin: https://myservice.com 
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin 
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors 
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty 
Referer: https://myservice.comService.aspx?AGU=1&[...] 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7 
Cookie: BIGipServerSD_Home=224813834.20480.0000; ASP.NET_SessionId=152i5tiwq1r2cbiuamxxxxxx; PVUE=00
```

Comment: Is the XHR request sent as `application/json` content-type or some other content-type? Can you share in your question the request information from the Network tab in your web browser?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule It's `application/json`. I added the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Content-type` header](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize/blob/v0.4.5/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py#L1154) in mechanize request sent to the server is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Set `Content-type` to `application/json` in `headers` parameter passed in [request](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser_api.html#mechanize.Request)

```py
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
request = mechanize.Request(
    url='https://external.site/server.asmx/LoadControl',
    data=body,
    method='POST',
    headers=headers
)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the first part of the puzzle. I also had to change the payload - `urllib.parse.urlencode` is good for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but since I went for `application/json`, I had to run it through `json.dumps()` instead. You got me to the right solution, thanks a lot!